# Solr sort doesn't work expectedly

Tags: solr

Have a field "title" with the definition

```
<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I want to display the results in order by score, and if it is tied, in order by title as the secondary sort.

However, when queried with `sort=score desc, title asc`, the results don't necessarily come in the ascending order for title.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorting doesn't work well on multivalued and tokenized fields.

Documentation - 
Sorting can be done on the "score" of the document, or on any multiValued="false" indexed="true" field provided that field is either non-tokenized (ie: has no Analyzer) or uses an Analyzer that only produces a single Term (ie: uses the KeywordTokenizer)

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort

Use string as the field type and copy the title field into the new field.

```
<field name="title_sort" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="title_sort" />
```